# React-native erro apos instalar lib react-native-router-flux

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, react-native, react

Apos instalar a lib react-native-router-flux no meu app apareceu este erro no:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz o procedimento de remover a pasta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse não é um problema da lib router-flux, é um erro da versão mais nova na lib babel-preset-react-native.

Para solucionar o erro, basta seguir os procedimentos que informei no link abaixo:

[Erro ao tentar rodar app no emulador do android studio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/231676/erro-ao-tentar-rodar-app-no-emulador-do-android-studio/232165#232165)